# Getting javascript function to work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a website for a school project and I'm having trouble with using the javascript. I am not a fan of js because I always have issues with it and I can never seem to get them figured out without help, but it is one of the requirements for the project. I am trying to make the title in the page move in from off the left side of the page and into the center when the page loads. Here is my code:

JS:

```
function animate() {
    function movetext() {
        obj = document.getElementById('spacer');
        obj.style.position ='relative';
        obj.style.left = '-100px'; //still needs to be adjusted
    }

    function moveright() {
        obj.style.alignContent="center";
        obj.style.animation="move 2s";
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Lockport, NY - Activities</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script+Swash+Caps' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body onload="animate();">

<!-- Background -->
<div class="background">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <?php
        include 'includes/nav.php';
    ?>

    <!-- Title -->
    <div id="spacer"><p span class="titles">Activities...</p></div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main">
           //code removed for readability

        </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <?php
        include 'includes/footer.php';
     ?>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
<script src="project1.js"></script>
</html>
```

I know I'm not the greatest when it comes to coding, and I know its probably a simple fix but I can't find it. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with CSS animations:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('spacer').classList.add('show');
}, 100);
```

```css
#spacer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  transition: right 3s;
}

#spacer.show {
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="spacer">
  <p class="titles">
     Hello
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution for this would be to use two classes (e.g. .centerpos, .title) and just assign the class with the styling for centering the text via js.

So it would look something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Lockport, NY - Activities</title>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script+Swash+Caps' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <style>
        .title {
            position: absolute;
            left: -100px;
            transition: left 2s;
        }
        .title.centerpos {
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        }
    </style>
    <body onload="document.querySelector('.title').classList.add('centerpos');">
        <div class="background">
            <div id="spacer"><p span class="titles title">Activities...</p></div>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="main">
                   //code removed for readability

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```